# Calculus - Integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

Hello I am currently stuck at integration by parts. And I was wondering why at the second $u$ substitution I should choose $u=\cos 3x$ instead of the $\sin 2x$. Is there a specific rule which applies?

[image]

Best,
Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try it for yourself and see: let $u=\sin 2x$ and $dv=\cos 3xdx$. Then $du=2\cos 2x dx$ and $v=\frac13\sin 3x$, so

$$\int\cos 3x\sin 2x dx=\frac13\sin 2x\sin 3x-\frac23\int\sin 3x\cos 2x dx\;,$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\int\sin 3x\cos 2x dx&=\frac12\sin 3x\sin 2x-\frac32\int\cos 3x\sin 2x dx\\
&=\frac12\sin 3x\sin 2x-\frac32\left(\frac13\sin 2x\sin 3x-\frac23\int\sin 3x\cos 2x dx\right)\\
&=\int\sin 3x\cos 2x dx\;,
\end{align*}$$

which is obviously true but not very helpful!

The general rule in this situation is that you should let the second $u$ be the part that came from the original $du$; otherwise you simply undo the first integration by parts, just as I did here. (Note that while you might not come up with the general rule on your own, you *can* discover something about the problem just by trying. Never be afraid to try something; first, it might work, and secondly, even if it doesn’t, you’ll have learned something.)

Comment: Yes that is probably the best way to go about those integrations ;) Thanks for your help, I will review my work :)

Comment: @Sebastian: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a $u$ that was $dv$ before you will get back where you started.  The idea is to exploit the fact that taking two derivatives of $\cos$ get you back something that looks like the original but has a minus sign.  If you do $$\int u dv=uv-\int v du$$ then integrate by parts again you get $$\int u dv=uv-\int v du=uv-\left(uv-\int udv\right)$$ which is not very interesting.